# Why I can not generate key with keytool and RSA?

Tags: java, algorithm, cordova, ionic-framework, rsa

So this is what I tried

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

But I am getting this..

```
keytool error: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: RSA KeyGenerator not available
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: RSA KeyGenerator not available
```

What should I do ?

p.s using: jdk1.8.0_121

Comment: Works for me. `java version "1.8.0_40"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When the command `keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000` is executed there is no errors, this is an example of the output.

```
Generating 2,048 bit RSA key pair and self-signed certificate (SHA256withRSA) with a validity of 10,000 days    for: CN=a, OU=a, O=a, L=a, ST=a, C=a
Enter key password for <mykey>
    (RETURN if same as keystore password):  
[Storing my-release-key.jks]
```

But what causes the `java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: RSA KeyGenerator not available`?

This error means that keytool attempts to instantiate a KeyGenerator object throught an RSA invalid algorithm.  Why RSA is an invalid algorithm for KeyGenerator?  It is because RSA is an algorithm for *Asymmetric keys* and KeyGenerator is a class that creates *Symmetric keys*.

Now lets make some test to clarify ideas and create a KeyGenerator object using RSA:

```
public class KeyGeneratorTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            KeyGenerator keyGeneratorTest=KeyGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The previous code generates the same exception reported in the question:

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: RSA KeyGenerator not available
    at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.<init>(KeyGenerator.java:169)
    at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyGenerator.java:223)
```

Now I will try to create a symmetric key using keytool and RSA algorithm parameter.

```
keytool -genseckey -alias mytest2 -keyalg RSA -keysize 192 -storetype JCEKS
```

The output is exactly the same as reported from question.

```
keytool error: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: RSA KeyGenerator not available
```

The error is thrown because internally `keytool -genseckey` command attempts to create a KeyGenerator object using the RSA algorithm parameter (`-keyalg RSA`) and as I mention RSA is not a valid algorithm for symetric key creation.

Please visit the following documentation to know more about keytool. 
[List of Java Standard Algorithm Names](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#KeyGenerator), [NoSuchAlgorithmException Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/KeyGenerator.html), [Keytool source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/sun/security/tools/keytool/Main.java?av=f) and [Keytool reference documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html#keytool_option_genseckey)

Comment: Try it why? What is the solution being given here?

Comment: Define the alias argument is always a good practice to avoid errors related to keystore creation, and the error will depend on the environment but in this case the answer is a suggestion to create keystore with good practices.

Comment: @DanielC., it would be great if you add this comment to your answer.

Comment: The [-alias](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html#keytool_option_genkeypair) option is not required, and is not the source of the error message.

Comment: Re your edit, you should remove the 'try this' part and put your final conclusion #2 right at the top where it can be seen, and in a simpler form.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use

```
keytool -genseckey -keystore my-release.pf12 -deststoretype pkcs12 -keyalg AES -keysize 256 -storepass <passwd> -keypass <passwd> -noprompt
```